# Prove sine addition formula using Identity Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I want to prove that $\sin(z+w)=\sin(z)\cos(w)+\cos(z)\sin(w) ∀z,w ∈ ℂ$ using the [Identity Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) and [Zeros of an Analytic Functions](http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/rdaileda/teach/s20/m4364/lectures/zeros_handout.pdf).

I know how to solve this problem using exponential function but I want to solve using the theorems I have learned.

My attempt:
I fixed $w$ as a real number and showed that both functions agree for every $z$ in $ℂ$. This is for $w$ in $ℝ$. The question is how prove this for $w ∈ ℂ$?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Then please show us your motivation, your attempts, and where you got stuck.

Comment: @AnneBauval ,Ok) I edited

Comment: Oh, well done! Then, for a fixed $z\in\Bbb C,$ let $f,g:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ be your two (analytic) functions of $z:$ $f(z)=\sin(z+w),$ $g(z)=\dots.$ Since they coincide on $\Bbb R,$ they coincide on $\Bbb C.$

Comment: @AnneBauval , I understand. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry, I meant $f,g$ functions of $w,$ not of $z,$ which is fixed. But I am sure you understood.